# How to return each recursive function call in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I might not be using the correct terminology, but I am rather new to programming (so forgive me if this is an easy search, I am not sure if I am using the correct keywords).

Let's say I have a recurrence relation:

f(0) = 2

f(x) = f(x-1) + 1 for x >= 1.

Now, let's say I want to program this relation using recursion in Python (2.7), but instead of returning just f(x), I want to return a list: [ f(x), f(x-1), ..., f(0) ].

I can easily program the recurrence relation to return f(10):

```
def my_fun(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1+my_fun(x-1)
```

However, I am at a loss as of how to return each function call without using a for loop.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I would like to avoid using a for loop if possible.

Comment: Is not using a for loop one of your requirements? You did not make that clear. Also, could you return a list in the reverse order of the one you show; i.e. `[f(0), f(1), ..., f(x)]`? That would make more sense and is close to dynamic programming or memoization.

Comment: I am trying to avoid a for loop because I have noticed I use them "too much," even when not necessary.

And yes, reverse order is fine.

Comment: @amarsh I don't understand your comment about for-loop. FYI, a for-loop is typically more efficient than recursion and therefore preferred. Recursion is ok sometimes and maybe you're not sensitive to the timing. Your stated reason - that you use for-loops too often - doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Brick What I meant is that I already know how to solve it using a loop. I am trying to practice solving problems using different approaches and recursion is one of my weaker areas. At least, programming recursion, I have no issue with the concept thanks to my math background. Since I knew the problem could be solved with recursion, I wanted to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a `list` and use the last element to calculate the value in the previous call.

```
def my_fun(x):
    if x == 0:
        return [2]
    else:
        l = my_fun(x-1)
        l.append(l[-1] + 1) # since f(n-1) is in the last element

        return l

a = my_fun(5)

print(a)
```